# "you poked my heart…"

Tags: idioms

I've just watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sKdDyyanGk) and I was just wondering if there is an idiom "to poke someone in the heart" which could mean "you get me to fall in love with you" or something?

Or does the sentence "you poked my heart" imply only physical motion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Toddlers are literal**

This video shows toddlers arguing and play-fighting.  (The boy does not know how to defend himself, nor is he used to getting hurt.  The pugilistic girl does not know how dangerous poking someone in the eye is.)  Toddlers tend to either be very literal, or quote things that they have heard.  In this video, the pugilistic girl literally pokes the boy on the left side of his chest.  Thus, it is only a slight exaggeration to say that she poked him in the heart, using the literal meanings of the words.

**Metaphors**

"You touched my heart" is a common metaphor.  It is usually said by someone who has felt sympathy, or happiness, or sadness, as a result of something someone else did.  Sometimes this sentiment leads to love.  "You warmed my heart" and "You melted my heart" are similar expressions -- unless said by one of Oz's (fictional) wicked witches:

> They had hearts that were literally made of ice, and melting their hearts would kill them.

"You broke my heart" is another common metaphor.  It is often said by someone who loves someone else, but that second person has died, or ended the relationship on poor terms.  It is also used for something that gets one's hopes up (such as a sports team coming within 59 seconds of winning a championship) but then utterly crushes those hopes (for example, by fumbling away the ball at the goal line).

Hypothetically, "You poked my heart" could be a metaphor that means something in between.

Comment: How do I add "spoiler tags"?  I want to hide the info about the Wicked Witch of the West.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to spoiler that.

Comment: The only way I know is to use `>!` instead of `>` to make a blockquote, but I agree that it is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung -- Thank you.  I think it is appropriate to spoiler tag that info, especially considering that the people in the video are young enough to be surprised by the climactic scene of *The Wizard of Oz*.  Plus, many English language learners might not have had the pleasure of seeing the movie, either.